# Searching on full name in any combination of first, middle, last names is taking too much time

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

```
WHERE p.DeleteInd = 0
    AND (
        nullif(@v_PhoneNo, '') IS NULL
        OR cast(p.MobileNo AS NVARCHAR(20)) LIKE '%' + @v_PhoneNo + '%'
        OR cast(p.ContactNo AS NVARCHAR(20)) LIKE '%' + @v_PhoneNo + '%'
        )
    AND (
        isnull(@v_PatientDisplayId, '') = ''
        OR p.PatientDisplayId = @v_PatientDisplayId
        )
    AND (
        nullif(@v_OldPatientMRNO, '') IS NULL
        OR p.OldMrno = @v_OldPatientMRNO
        )
    AND (
        nullif(@v_SearchText, '') IS NULL
        OR p.FirstName LIKE @v_SearchText + '%'
        OR p.LastName LIKE @v_SearchText + '%'
        OR p.MiddleName LIKE @v_SearchText + '%'
        OR cast(p.MobileNo AS NVARCHAR(20)) LIKE '%' + @v_SearchText + '%'
        OR CONCAT (
            FirstName
            ,' '
            ,MiddleName
            ,' '
            ,LastName
            ) LIKE @v_SearchText + '%'
        OR CONCAT (
            p.FirstName
            ,' '
            ,p.LastName
            ) LIKE '%' + @v_SearchText + '%'
        OR CONCAT (
            p.FirstName
            ,' '
            ,p.MiddleName
            ,' '
            ,p.LastName
            ,' '
            ,p.SecondLastName
            ) LIKE '%' + @v_SearchText + '%'
        OR CONCAT (
            p.FirstName
            ,' '
            ,p.SecondLastName
            ) LIKE '%' + @v_SearchText + '%'
        OR CONCAT (
            p.LastName
            ,' '
            ,p.SecondLastName
            ) LIKE '%' + @v_SearchText + '%'
        )
    AND (
        nullif(@Mobile, 0) IS NULL
        OR p.MobileNo LIKE '%' + @Mobile + '%'
        )
```

Comment: Sample data would help your question, but trivially, you could store the first, middle, and last names in separate columns.

Comment: The `ORs` would be the worst part of your query, some of them are even duplicate. Consider full text indexes and the name stored as one field.

Answer (score 0):

Two easy and hopefully good enough optimizations:

- Remove the leading %, keep only the trailing one (meaning the searches will only be "something that starts with the typed text"

  ```
  WHERE p.DeleteInd = 0
      AND (
          nullif(@v_PhoneNo, '') IS NULL
          OR cast(p.MobileNo AS NVARCHAR(20)) LIKE @v_PhoneNo + '%'
          OR cast(p.ContactNo AS NVARCHAR(20)) LIKE @v_PhoneNo + '%'
          )
      AND (
          isnull(@v_PatientDisplayId, '') = ''
          OR p.PatientDisplayId = @v_PatientDisplayId
          )
      AND (
          nullif(@v_OldPatientMRNO, '') IS NULL
          OR p.OldMrno = @v_OldPatientMRNO
          )
      AND (
          nullif(@v_SearchText, '') IS NULL
          OR p.FirstName LIKE @v_SearchText + '%'
          OR p.LastName LIKE @v_SearchText + '%'
          OR p.MiddleName LIKE @v_SearchText + '%'
          OR cast(p.MobileNo AS NVARCHAR(20)) LIKE @v_SearchText + '%'
          OR CONCAT (
              FirstName
              ,' '
             ,MiddleName
              ,' '
              ,LastName
              ) LIKE @v_SearchText + '%'
          OR CONCAT (
              p.FirstName
              ,' '
              ,p.LastName
              ) LIKE @v_SearchText + '%'
          OR CONCAT (
              p.FirstName
              ,' '
              ,p.MiddleName
              ,' '
              ,p.LastName
              ,' '
              ,p.SecondLastName
              ) LIKE @v_SearchText + '%'
          OR CONCAT (
              p.FirstName
              ,' '
              ,p.SecondLastName
              ) LIKE @v_SearchText + '%'
          OR CONCAT (
              p.LastName
              ,' '
              ,p.SecondLastName
              ) LIKE @v_SearchText + '%'
          )
      AND (
          nullif(@Mobile, 0) IS NULL
          OR p.MobileNo LIKE @Mobile + '%'
          )
  ```
- Make sure you have indexes on FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, SecondLastName and MobileNo. Assuming you want to optimize read and you don't have too many writes, that should take your query orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks Dynamic query. before trying to rewrite the query, please try to add OPTION (RECOMPILE) after your WHERE clause and see if you get any performance enhancements.

```
where ...
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```